# JPA does not return default value after saving

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I faced a problem.
A have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "date_create", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Date dateCreate;

}
```

DDL of the related table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  date_create TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

I have such logic:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Transactional
  public User createUser() {
    return userRepository(new User());
  }
 }

 @Service
 public class Service2 {

   @Autowired
   private Service1 service1;

   public void createUser() {
     User createdUser = service1.createUser();
     System.out.println(createdUser.getDateCreate()); // actual result : null
   }
  }
```

Field **dateCreate** is set by DB function now() but it is not returned by JPA in created entity.

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Without using Hibernate or Spring specific tools. Just JPA.**

Comment: You will need to refresh the entity from the db else it won't work.

Comment: I used 'saveAndFlush' but it didn't help me( 
Can I get actual entity data without calling additional queries?

Comment: `createdUser = userRepository.saveAndFlush(createdUser);`?

Comment: As mentioned use refresh (which is an actyual method on the entitymanager).

Comment: 'saveAndFlush' didn't help me(
refresh from EntityManager did it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `refresh` the data after saving it to the database and to get the latest state of the object, as `entityManager.refresh(createdUser)`

You can use it as mentioned below.

```
 @Service
 public class Service2 {

   @Autowired
   private Service1 service1;

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   public void createUser() {
     User createdUser = service1.createUser();
     entityManager.refresh(createdUser);
     System.out.println(createdUser.getDateCreate()); // actual result : null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the anotation @PrePersist to create the date before persisting.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
    
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue
          private Integer id;
        
          @Column(name = "date_create")
          @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
          private Date dateCreate;


          @PrePersist
          private void onCreate() {
          dateCreate= new Date();
         }
        
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I thought about it. But we use 'default now()' in DDL and we rely on that. May be there are other solutions that can return actual 'dateCreate' value?
I used @CreationTimestamp from Hibernate and it worked perfectly. But I don't want to be tied with specific JPA implementation features.

Comment: You can try calling the method refresh after the update. By the way the annotation @PrePersist is part of the JPA standard specification isn't vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "date_create", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private LocaleDate dateCreate;

}
```

OR

```
private LocaleDateTime dateCreate;
```

1. LocaleDate is store date into database without time.
2. LocaleDateTime is store date with time into database.